# how to store multidimentional array with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multidimensional-array

I want to build a page that contain question and choises. for simplification, consider this code:

```
<div id="page">
   <div class="number"> 
       <p class="question">Question 1</p> 
       <ul class="choise">
            <li> Choise a </li>
            <li> Choise b </li>
            <li> Choise c </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="number"> 
       <p class="question">Question 2</p> 
       <ul class="choise">
            <li> Choise a </li>
            <li> Choise b </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="number"> 
       <p class="question">Question 3</p> 
       <ul class="choise">
            <li> Choise a </li>
            <li> Choise b </li>
            <li> Choise c </li>
            <li> Choise d </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<button value="submit" type="button" onClick="submitSurvey()" />
```

Can every one please help me how to define submitSurvey() function to get all of the question and its choises, and then submit them via server?

I've thinked to get all of the each question and its answer by calling jquery each() function, but I dont know how to store them via array, since it will be multidimentional array and then submit them to php script.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: regardless of what you want, you have UL's and not radio inputs.  So the data can't be submitted anyway.  After the fact, you need to serialize the form and attach it to the request.

Comment: You can't with this html. You first need to create Html form and then you don't have to do anything you can just serialise form data and send it to server. The server will receive these selected options in $_GET or $_POST depending upon your method (POST or GET). Better look first on how to create html forms and then how to submit html form through ajax.

Comment: @rafael: ok, i just give the example just for simplication. but I dont think so if the data can't be submitted anyway. We can still use jquery each() function right to get the question text and choises? but I dont know how to store them in array and then submit via ajax.

Comment: @poush: you're right. But it's not my point since for reason of front end viewing. So I dont want to use input text html for question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `jquery` and`serializeArray` this code submit a multi-dimentional array with questions and answers to a php script file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['questions'])) 
    var_dump($_POST['questions']);

?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function ConvertSerialAToJSA( data )
    {
        var js_array = Array();

        $.each(data, function (index, el) 
        {
            if (!js_array[el.name]) 
            {
                js_array[el.name] = [el.value];
            } 
            else 
            {
                js_array[el.name].push(el.value);
            }
        });

        return js_array;
    }

    function submitSurvey()
    {
        //get the form data in a serialized array format.
        var data = $('#questions_and_answers').serializeArray();

        //javascript associative array - indexed with 'questions[1][answer]' keys.
        var arr = ConvertSerialAToJSA(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/",
            type:'post',
            data: $.param(data),
            success: function( html_data )
                {
                    $("html").html( html_data );
                }
        });     
    }

</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" id="questions_and_answers">
            <div id="page">
               <div class="number"> 
                   <p class="question">Question 1 <input type='text' name='questions[1][question]'/> </p> 
                   <ul class="choise">
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[1][answer]' value='a'> Choice a</input></li>
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[1][answer]' value='b'> Choice b</input></li>
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[1][answer]' value='c'> Choice c</input></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="number"> 
                   <p class="question">Question 2 <input type='text' name='questions[2][question]'/> </p> 
                   <ul class="choise">
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[2][answer]' value='a'> Choice a</input></li>
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[2][answer]' value='b'> Choice b</input></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="number"> 
                   <p class="question">Question 3 <input type='text' name='questions[3][question]'/> </p> 
                   <ul class="choise">
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[3][answer]' value='a'> Choice a</input></li>
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[3][answer]' value='b'> Choice b</input></li>
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[3][answer]' value='c'> Choice c</input></li>
                    <li><input type='radio' name='questions[3][answer]' value='d'> Choice d</input></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>

               <input type="button" value="Save form" onclick='submitSurvey()' />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My own test output from `var_dump($_POST['questions']);` (after submission) gives:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["question"]=>
    string(3) "one"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["question"]=>
    string(3) "two"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["question"]=>
    string(5) "three"
    ["answer"]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
}
```

for input:

[image]

> Note that `var arr = ConvertSerialAToJSA(data);` is only included for
>   demonstrative purposes.

Comment: Does it need to be ajax specifically?

Comment: but how to get question text with your methods? it's just get choises text right?

Comment: is the question text entered by the user into the form?

Comment: First I would thanks to you. But I'm very sorry, It's not really help.The reason why I will avoid using plain html form to submit is because the user can add new question, delete it, update it, and also save the form.

if we use html form to submit, how about this scenario?
1) user create 5 question
2) user save them
3) user update question number 2
4) user re-save them.

with plain html, it's difficult to know which question has been updated.